# What algebraic structure characterizes all natural operations between differential operators and differential forms?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, smooth-manifolds, qa.quantum-algebra

On a smooth manifold $M$ one can define various algebraic structures, natural with respect to diffeomorphisms:

- the differential graded-commutative algebra $\Omega(M)$ of differential forms on $M$;
- the jet algebra $J(M)$ of $M$;
- the filtered algebra $D(M)$ of differential operators on $M$;
- the Gerstenhaber algebra $\Lambda(M)$ of multivector fields on $M$ (the associated graded algebra of $D(M)$).

These structures have numerous relations and operations between them,
like Cartan's homotopy formula $L_X=[d,\iota_X]$,
[Cartan calculus](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cartan+calculus),
the left D-module structure on $\Omega^0(M)$ and the right D-module structure on $\Omega^{\text{top}}(M)$,
and many others.

Numerous papers exist that axiomatize and study part of this structure with some of the relations (e.g., the Tamarkin-Tsygan calculus).
However, I am not aware of a result that would axiomatize *all* of the relations,
i.e., exhibit an algebraic structure that would allow one to deduce all relations between any of the above operations.

It is plausible that such an axiomatization may exist.
For instance, the book by Kolář, Michor, and Slovák ([Natural operations in differential geometry](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf))
contains numerous results on all sorts of natural operations between the above bundles,
and classifies many different types of such natural operations.

**What algebraic structure axiomatizes all natural operations between the above bundles?**

An answer for a limited subset of the above structures would also be helpful.
For instance, can we characterize completely the algebraic structure of differential operators and differential forms, taken together?

Motivation for this question comes from a desire to understand
to what extent the classical Thom–Whitney–Quillen–Sullivan construction
of polynomial differential forms on a simplicial set
can be extended to include things like differential operators, etc.

Comment: This is a great question! Algebraically it's prob best if we work universally, so in terms of representation theory of the pro unipotent group of automorphisms of a formal disc. In which case I think all such "univ" bundles are gotten from \omega, by taking tensor powers, duals, and extensions (the basic such being the atiyah class). So we have a tensor cat and an object \omega and we want to know all the structure we get as above, which should be encoded in a sort of extended (derived) endom operad (extended to allow the duals and derived to allow the extensions). No idea if this helps!